# Can't push to friend's public repo even though I am a collaborator

Tags: git, github

I cloned my friend's repo and tried to push the comments I inserted with

```
git push -u origin reviewnotesbranch
```

I am prompted for my username and pass which I put in but I get the error

```
remote: Anonymous access to user/cs288.git denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/user/cs288.git/'
```

I checked my

```
git config --list
```

and it looks like my user.email and user.name are still set properly to my email and name. What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

EDIT:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bunchle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
user.email=mygit'semail
user.name=myname
core.editor=emacs
corerepositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
then branches and remotes with https and ssh links
```

**EDIT2:
    after pulling some changes from a collaborator on MY project and rebasing them, I'm getting the SAME Anonymous access denied to MY OWN git. and Authentication failed for my own https's url**

Comment: Can you kindly paste your `git config -list`. You can maskoff email if you like.

Comment: this is a support request for assistance with github, and github support are much more likely to prove helpful.


Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the rebasing action was only half done the entire time resulting in my git activities becoming **completely** frozen. After completing the rebasing process, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't locate this repo: https://github.com/user/cs288.git

I suspect `remote origin` is incorrectly configured in your `git config`

Set your new URL using:

```
git remote set-url origin <newurl> [<oldurl>]
```

*Reference: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html*

Comment: `"... so my friend's code wouldnt be seen"` I couldn't understand this.

Comment: I get 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I have had my friend double check that I am a collaborator.

Comment: I could not access `https://github.com/user/cs288.git`? Can you double check the repo. Also, paste output of your `git config -l`

Comment: The repo is a dumby since my friend doesn't want it shown and that's probably not the problem since now I am getting the same error for my own repo after a rebase! (I can't seem to push anything now)

Answer (score 0):

```
remote: Anonymous access to user/cs288.git denied
```

Note the critical word, 'anonymous'. You need to be nonymous. Either supply credentials over https, or switch to (much easier) ssh.

Comment: What do you mean? 
Not only am I entering my username and password when prompted, I'm logged in on the website, my git config -list also has my email and username

Comment: Logging into the site is completely unrelated. I think you need help from github support, they are very quick to give assistance and can diagnose your problem. I don't think you are entering the right name and password, but how could I tell for sure?

Comment: I'm getting this error toward my own repo now after taking in a collaborator's changes and rebasing them. (Same error as me trying to push to the friend's project who I am collaborating on)